# Setting visual editor with storyblok and nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, storyblok

I am new in storyblok with nuxt. I am using chrome with windows 10. My nuxt app is static, ssr true.

I am following the next tutorial to make my first app - https://www.storyblok.com/tp/nuxt-js-multilanguage-website-tutorial
All was working well except when I try to set the visual editor.
I went into the Settings and in the General tab to change the value of the Location (default environment) to http://localhost:3000/.
I changed and saved  it.

After that, when I click 'home' content I get the nuxt page error  that disappears quickly and the browser open a blank page with a chrome debug console error:

```
'bridge:24 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
    at https://app.storyblok.com/bridge:24:26'
```

After that if click the chrome back button, It never come back to previous page, and I have to go manually restart to space area if I want to try again.

I know the problem is related to 'home' slug, as said in the tutorial. My app has no 'home'  page . But if I follow the tutorial that said to change the realpath to '/' I am unable to get visual editor working with my nuxt app in http://localhost:3000. I allways get the same error.

I have noted the problem happened only in chrome.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue in Chrome, make you you allow third party cookies on the preview editor page and it should work.